# PHP Datetime->format returning wrong ordinal suffix

Tags: php, datetime

I have a UTC time string that is not playing nice with PHP's `DateTime->format` function.

I create a new php file and paste in the following:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', 1567209600, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane') );

die( $date->format( 'l, nS F Y' ) );
```

I am getting:

```
Saturday, 8st August 2019
```

For starters, the correct date is 31, and the ordinal suffix for 8 should be 'th'. What is actually going on here? There is no other code in this file.

Answer (score 1):

Note the codes are case sensitive. `N` is ordinal day of the week and `n` is the ordinal month. You want `j`, which is day of the month without leading zeroes: `l, jS F Y`

Comment: oh my GOOOOOOOD I'M A MORON

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', 1567209600, new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane') );

var_dump($date);
```

The time zone is not set correctly.

Output

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-08-31 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" }
```

If the date was created from a timestamp, the time zone is always UTC. You must use setTimeZone after create to transfer to your time zone.